# crud using azure service with online-offline syncing in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am stack on linking xamarin.android  and azure cloud,i want to be able to perform crud operations and also offline-online syncing?any samples code or direction will be really appreciated.

how to we store and retrieve images on the azure cloud by uploading them from the android app gallery to the cloud and also retrieve them for view both online and offline in xamarin.android ..kindly help

This is what i know.....the models must be the same on both the local db and the azure or asp.net web api....i want to know how to perform the crud and how to sync the data to azure db and local db(pulling and pushing data)....you can employee model which has id,name image and age property to give me an example,my mail is rapelathomas@gmail.com....you can sketch me some quick code on notepad....hehehe cheers

Answer (score 0):

> how to we store and retrieve images on the azure cloud by uploading them from the android app gallery to the cloud and also retrieve them for view both online and offline in xamarin.android ..kindly help

Here is git code sample about [app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files) which uses the file management feature of Azure Mobile Apps SDK and provides the following features, you could refer to it:

- Scalable and efficient communication. Client **performs upload and download operations directly against blob storage**, so the mobile backend does not create a bottleneck.
- Client-side support for association of files and records. Files are simply data that is related to a record, and do not need to be managed separately by the developer.
- **Offline sync support for file upload and download**. A client app can queue upload and download operations for when there is network connectivity.